# Different color points from an array in matplotlib animation

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, colors

I'm trying to get a different color for each point in this animation. I would like to pass the array c_state as the hue-value of a hsv-tuple for each point. So far everything I tried has failed. I've tried using this in the animate function:

```
particles.set_color(pbox.color[:,0],1.0,1.0)
```

But I'm getting warning that only length-1 arrays can be converted to scalars.
I've also tried making length-3 arrays using np.random and trying to convert those to rgb-tuples but that didn't work either. I have trouble finding the right data-structure to pass to the color variable of ax.plot.
The colors only have to be set once and don't need to change during the animation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.animation as anim
import numpy as np
import colorsys
from random import random

n = 250

class ParticleBox:

    def __init__(self,i_state,c_state):
        self.i_state = np.asarray(i_state, dtype=float)
        self.c_state = np.asarray(c_state, dtype=float)

        self.state = self.i_state.copy()
        self.color = self.c_state.copy()

i_state = -5 + 10 * np.random.random((n, 2))
c_state = np.random.random((n, 1))

pbox = ParticleBox(i_state, c_state)

fig = plt.figure()
ax =  fig.add_subplot(111, xlim=(-10,10), ylim=(-10,10))

particles, = ax.plot([], [], 'o', ms=5)

def init():
    global pbox 
    particles.set_data([],[])

    return particles,

def animate(i):
    global pbox, ax, fig
    particles.set_data(pbox.state[:,0],pbox.state[:,1])

    return particles,

ani = anim.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = 500, 
                         interval = 10, blit=True, 
                         init_func=init)
plt.show()
```

Comment: *How* has it failed, so far?

Comment: I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line plot `plt.plot()` in matplotlib has exactly one color. You cannot set different colors to its segments.

What you need is a scatter plot `plt.scatter`. You can update a scatter plot using

```
sc = plt.scatter(x,y, c=.., s =.., cmap="hsv")
sc.set_offsets(np.c_[x,y]) # set positions
sc.set_array(color) # set color
```

`color` in this case would be a 1D array of values between 0 and 1. Those values would be mapped to hsv colors using the `hsv` colormap, which is specified in the `cmap` argument to scatter.

[image]

Complete code would look as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.animation as anim
import numpy as np

n = 140

class ParticleBox:
    def __init__(self,i_state,c_state):
        self.i_state = np.asarray(i_state, dtype=float)
        self.c_state = np.asarray(c_state, dtype=float)
        self.state = self.i_state.copy()
        self.color = self.c_state.copy()
    def iterate(self):
        self.state += (np.random.random((n, 2))-0.5)/3.
        self.state[self.state > 10.] = 10
        self.state[self.state < -10] = -10
        self.color += (np.random.random(n)-0.5)/89.
        self.color[self.color>1.] = 1.
        self.color[self.color<0] = 0.


i_state = -5 + 10 * np.random.random((n, 2))
c_state = np.random.random(n)

pbox = ParticleBox(i_state, c_state)

fig = plt.figure()
ax =  fig.add_subplot(111, xlim=(-10,10), ylim=(-10,10))

particles = ax.scatter([], [], c=[],s=25, cmap="hsv", vmin=0, vmax=1)

def animate(i):
    pbox.iterate()
    particles.set_offsets(pbox.state)
    particles.set_array(pbox.color)
    return particles,

ani = anim.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = 140, 
                         interval = 10, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: How I would go about making the size of the particles dynamic too? I've tried passing another 'set_array()' but that makes all the particles really small.

Comment: `.set_array()` determines the color. For the size use `.set_sizes()`.